# Wrong Drawable Color at LayerList

Tags: android

I just want to add background in my `ImageButton`

Here is what I'm doing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/colorDivider" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorButtonBlue"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:top="@dimen/circle_padding"
        android:left="@dimen/circle_padding"
        android:right="@dimen/circle_padding"
        android:bottom="@dimen/circle_padding"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_mic">

    </item>
</layer-list>
```

It adds the blue background and border around the image but my problem is that `ic_mic` has white color icon generated from `imageAssets` but it adds a blue background it also has some blue shade in `ic_mic` as you can see in the pic.
I want the pure white `ic_mic`. Can you please let me know why it's adding blue shade and how can I remove it

[image: icon with background color]

**Update ic_mic**

It's in `png` form. Check below pic
[image]

**Update: Same problem in when I'm using Switch**

If you set any background to `switch` it will also create a shade on `switch`

```
<Switch
   andoird:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@color/red" />
```

Comment: If ic_mic is a vector drawable, you may check its fill color and increase its opacity.

Comment: Are you sure your `ic_mic` image is fully opacity?

Comment: @Geros it's an `png` image not vector

Comment: @SiSa It's fully opacity, I update question please check it

Comment: Facing same problem, I'm using **Android Studio 3.1.3**

Comment: @AzeemHaider It's not fully opacity in above photo

Comment: you can use icon fonts like material icon and use text instead of drawable icon

Comment: The easy solution is to use the corresponding vector drawable from vector assets.

Comment: @masoudvali material icon also not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Use this Xml code as below

```
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/badge_notificatidon_2"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/item_count" 
    android:src="@drawable/ic_mic"/>//use src your icon 
    vector drawable or png image
```

In drawable resourse do like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<corners android:radius="8dp" />
<solid android:color="#01b9f5" />
<stroke
    android:width="3dip"
    android:color="#c6c6c6" />
<padding
    android:bottom="5dp"
    android:left="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:top="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Still same issue I don't know how you get it, which version of android studio you are using ? I have **3.1.3**

Comment: m using 3.1.0 android studio.In the drawable please import vector asset in drawable.>>drawable>>new>>vector Asset

Comment: i tried using .png extention also its working fine.Make sure u are using color in background and png image as src of image button.if it still happen then its a problem with image take another png.

Comment: Yes I also try this making a blue background and using image in source, I'm also facing this problem in `switch`

Comment: I think your image resolution is low.try another high resolution image

Comment: I created it from drawable -> new -> Image Asset. It may be a low resolution does it mean it adopt background color

Answer (score 0):

download ic_mic using vector Asset instead of image asset [it worked for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lPeC.jpg)

Comment: Thanks it's worked with image assets, But why it's not working with PNG ?

Comment: but I have some my own reasons I want to use png. isn't it possible in png